# Multiple references to the same class library

Tags: .net, dependencies, versioning, forward-compatibility

Let's assume that 2 years ago, I wrote a .NET class library, say `mylib.dll`, that heavily depends on an external library, say `foo.dll`, which is open sourced, MIT licensed (that's relevant, read on).

A lot of customers used my library, along with its dependency assembly. The package was `mylib.dll` with `foo.dll`.

Days went by, and the creators of `foo.dll` broke their API, and now they deployed a new version of their library. This new version includes most of the types that were included in the old version, but some of the methods are missing, or changed.

## The Problem

Some potential consumers already use `foo.dll` in its new version in their application, for their own uses. When I supply them `mylib.dll`, they can't use it. They can't even have a successful build, because `mylib.dll` wants the old version of `foo.dll` with its old methods and signatures.

## How to overcome this problem?

I'd like to have a forward compatible solution, so that this issue is not raised again. So I thought about several things:

1. Update my source code to use the new version of `foo.dll`. But that's a lot of work and time consuming. In addition, that's not forward compatible, since this issue might be raised again some day.
2. Since I have the source of the exact version of `foo.dll`, perhaps I can easily change its namespace and rebuild the whole thing. This way I can enjoy my own version of `foo.dll`, and that's legal since its license is MIT. I can name the modified assembly `mylib.foo.dll` or something like that. I can even merge the whole thing using `ILMerge` to something like `mylib.merged.dll`.
3. Redesign `mylib.dll` so that the needed functionality from `foo.dll` is separated into an interface and an implementation. In terms of engineering, that's the most elegant solution. In terms of time, that's a disaster and therefore cannot be considered a real solution.

## My Question

To accomplish #2 above, is there a short way of changing the namespace of a given source code?

Comment: Why not use a simple find-replace operation? You just need to replace `namespace foo` with `namespace mylib.foo` in all the files of `foo`. And then you will have to replace `using foo` with `using mylib.foo`. Done.

Comment: @RB, I think you're missing the point here, or I don't understand your suggestion. Do you suggest that new consumers should use the old version of `foo.dll`? If so, then that's not a wise business decision from my company's perspective.

Comment: @RonKlein But surely what you are suggesting in option 2 is that you are going to fork `foo.dll`, so your customers will have an old version of it anyway (as I imagine you are unlikely to maintain it to the same degree as the original authors - I know I wouldn't!). Or have I totally misunderstood?

Comment: @RB, option 2 indeed implies using an old version of `foo.dll`, but under an encapsulated namespace, so that `mylib.dll` could use it as long as it needs.

Comment: @RonKlein But why go to the hassle of doing that? Why not just use the old `foo.dll` directly. Please note I'm not suggesting you install `foo.dll` globally on the system. Install it local to your application (you've tagged the question as .NET which has excellent support for this sort of situation).

Comment: @RB.: I think the problem of Ron is the following: The application of the customers use a current version of `foo` for things *unrelated* to `mylib`. In addition, the application of the customers want to use functionality of `mylib`. They don't care that `mylib` uses `foo` internaly. Ron on the other hand is happy with that old version of `foo` he currently is using, because `mylib` is well tested with it. To summarize: The application uses the new version of `foo` directly and additionally the fork of the old version indirectly for the functionality of `mylib`.

Comment: (cont.) Without creating his own fork of `foo` there would need to be two different versions of `foo.dll` in the folder of the customers application which obviously is impossible.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, you got it right! I'll try to edit my question to have a clearer view.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Ahhhh. Your (cont.) makes it all clear. I had missed the point that Ron's library is itself being consumed by an application that *also* uses foo.dll. I'll admit that's a trickier nut to crack then :)

Comment: @RB.: You are missing that the customers application *and* `mylib` don't use the GAC, so they both expect `foo.dll` to be in the applications folder. But they need different versions. This has nothing to do with .NET. It's just attributed to the fact that the filesystem only cares about the name of a file, not about its version.

Comment: @RonKlein: Have you tried the suggestion in my very first comment? It should work.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I'll give it a shot. There are some dark corners in C#'s syntax when it comes to `namespace`, if I remember correctly. But I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @RonKlein: What dark corners are you talking about? I can't think of any.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, nested namespaces. Example: `namespace foo { namespace foo /* !! */ { ... } } `, but I think that this lib doesn't have any of those.

Comment: @RonKlein: Yeah, that special case would lead to a compile error, so it would be easily spotted. Using nested namespaces of the same name is pointless anyway, so it shouldn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not use many of the methods of the old `foo.dll` that went missing in the new one, a viable solution could be to link your code to the new `foo.dll`, and make something like `mylib.foo.legacy.dll` that contains the missing functions, which you can copy from the old `foo` source since it's open source and MIT licenced.

No matter what you do, take the newest version of `foo.dll` as base, it's very unlikely that the authors will go back to the old functionality. If you mark the legacy methods you copied from the old dll with the `[obsolete]` attribute, you will get compile warnings showing you where the old functions are still referenced. You could then over time work towards removing these references until the legacy dll can be completely removed.

Answer (score 0):

Aha! Yeah - this is a common pain of consumers of *popular* open source libs such as nlog, newtonsoft etc etc.

**1. ALLOW MULTIPLE FOO.DLL(s)**

Your problem stems from the fact that your output directory can only contain one copy of a DLL (because all versions share the same file name). Some products put the version number into the DLL file name to solve this - but I think this is ugly. You could use assembly binding redirects to store your DLLs dependencies in a bin/subfolder to prevent overwriting - but this is a bit of a hack better solved with the following solution...

**2. ILMERGE**

The easiest solution for *your* customers, is for you to package your assembly and its dependencies into a multi-module DLL - i.e. use [ILMerge to MERGE](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9364/Merging-NET-assemblies-using-ILMerge) foo.dll into your mylib.dll (yes, a DLL can contain multiple assemblies) - then your product appears to be dependency-less (it's not really, its dependencies are just supplied all in the one DLL! Nice!).

*This is a much nicer solution than trying to recompile foo.dll, or namespace search/replace because you don't have to mess with the dependency source code and risk breaking it... plus as soon as you start changing 3rd party source code, you have to maintain those changes - when they release a new version... here you go searching/replacing again...*

Problem solved.

WARNING: Remember, if your mylib.dll returned types declared in foo.dll to the calling program (your customers' programs) they may get a class-cast exception because their DLL is expecting a different version of the type. Hence, this solution is only recommended if your dependency on foo.dll is black-box (not exposed publicly). However, I expect this is not a problem for you, or your wouldn't be considering moving the FOO types into a different namespace.

Comment: Option (1) takes more programming, and thus might be time consuming and a bit risky. As for option (2), I thought about it even before asking the question, and tried it (the same thing you suggested). It seems that ILMerge doesn't work like this. It merely combines the assemblies into a single file, but assembly resolving still remains an issue. Did you try it yourself?

Comment: Hi Ron,
I don't follow what you mean 'assembly resolving doesn't work like this'. The only reason I can think of that this wouldnt be functioning correctly, is that Foo.DLL isn't strongly named. If this is the case, there there is not much you can do - the first copy of the assembly that loads into the runtime will be the one resolved by ALL dll references - in this case, I assume you are getting 'MemberNotFound Exceptions'? The solution would be to strongly name YOUR copy of Foo.dll, and then ILmerge it.

Comment: I just found this explanation which should help to take you through the steps: https://coderwall.com/p/vjynhq